# GitFlow: when to delete or freeze feature/release branches?

Tags: git, github, git-flow

Learning GitFlow and have some concerns that I haven't found answers to in any of the docs/articles I've read.

Per GitFlow, after the `release` branch has passed QA in some testing/staging environemnt, a production release occurs and the `release` branch gets merged into `master` (where it is also tagged w/ a version number) as well as *back* into `develop`.

I *believe* we ONLY need to merge back into `develop` IF bugs cropped up during the QA process that required changes being made directly to the `release` branch. **Yes?** I assume if `release` contains nothing new on it that we don't need to merge it with `develop` again, right?!

I assume this also implies that when changes *are* made to `release` during testing/QA, that if they don't get merged back into `develop`, that we open ourselves up to regressions, **right**? Meaning that if the `develop` branch never gets the changes added to it that QA requested during testing, that if the `release` branch gets blown away, those changes are lost.

I'm also unsure of what GitFlow prescribes for actually "*closing*" branches (both feature branches and `release` branch alike). After they are merged in, are feature branches deleted? Or somehow frozen for further revision? After merging into `master`/`develop` is `release` supposed to be deleted or frozen as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would always suggest that you follow the process and always attempt the merge of the release branch into develop.  If there are no commits that don't exist on the develop branch, then git will inform you of this.  You will have essentially have performed a no-op.

Correct, if you don't merge release to develop then you leave yourself open to regressions.  Even if the release branch gets deleted, you will still have a history of the commits that made it onto master branch, so you would still be able to recover them, by cherry picking out the commits as required.

You would create a new feature and release branch for each thing. For example, `feature/abc`, `feature/bdc`, `release/1.0.0` `release/1.1.0`, etc.  Once these features and releases are complete the branch is deleted and not used again.